# How to compare values in two rows having one similar row id having same year & month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to detect rows having same component_id where values are different but month & year in date are same.

My derived table after joining multiple tables -

```
component_id  value  date         id
1             100    2019-12-31   1
2             400    2019-12-31   2
1             111    2019-12-20   3
2             400    2018-12-20   4
1             221    2019-12-30   5
```

Required data format-

```
id1    id2    value1    value2    date1        date2        component_id  

1      3      100       111      2019-12-31   2019-12-20      1

1      5      100       221      2019-12-31   2019-12-30      1

3      5      111       221      2019-12-20   2019-12-30      1
```

I am not able to figure out the SQL code. Please help.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a self join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.component_id = t2.component_id and
        t1.value <> t2.value and
        date_trunc('month', t1.date) = date_trunc('month', 2.date) and
        t1.id < t2.id;
```

You can use a CTE so you don't have to repeat the logic for your derived table.

Comment: It works but returns two set of rows for one value mismatch like for pair of id 1 & 3 I get two rows 1-3 & 3-1. Is there a way to return only 1 set.

Comment: @bhaskarindian . . . The condition `t1.id < t2.id` should do that.